# Where are temporary Basic Authentication credentials stored?

Tags: .net, authentication, https, basic-authentication

After searching around for quite some time, I have still not found an answer to this question.

I'm building a Web API (.NET) that will use basic authentication over HTTPS. When a user logs in, they are asked if they want the browser to remember the login credentials. Each browser has their own password management solution that stores the credentials if the user clicks 'yes'.

As far as I'm aware, when a user is authenticated, the credentials are sent over with each request. That is fine if the login credentials are stored in the aforementioned password manager. However, if the user doesn’t consent to having their details stored, where does the browser pull those details to send along with each request?

Are they stored in memory, or perhaps in a temporary file? Or even in the password manager (on a temporary basis)?